# Read ID formed with angularjs from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a code that creates `divs` with `ng-repeat` and place the id based on one value

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $scope.items">
    <div id="ajs-{{item.title}}">{{text}}</div>
    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById("ajs-{{item.title}}") //<-I need to do something like this
        //The rest of my code...
    </script>
</div>
```

Now i need to call that `id` from the *javascript* placed below the div, but i can't use `{{item.title}}` inside the `script` tag.

I can't place that function in the angular controller.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered passing the function as a callback to your angular controller?

Comment: Why do you need DOM injections whihle using AngularJS?

Comment: What are you doing with the element / div ?

Comment: I'm doing something like this in the div http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/

Comment: Each heat map needs an ID to refer to the div element and place the heat map

Answer (score 0):

```
Try 
<div ng-repeat="item in $scope.items">
    <div ng-click="yourFunction($index)">{{item.title}}</div>
</div>
<script>
    function MainController($scope){
        $scope.yourFunction = function(index){
              playWithIndexHere..
        }
    }
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: He mentioned already that he cannot use an angular controller function for this.

Answer (score 0):

To link JavaScript to an element in AngularJS use an attribute directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $scope.items">
    <div my-directive id="ajs-{{item.title}}">{{text}}</div>
    <!--
    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById("ajs-{{item.title}}") //<-I need to do something like this
        //The rest of my code...
    </script>
    -->
</div>
```

Define the directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return { 
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.item.title);
        var id = "ajs-" + scope.item.title;
        //var element = document.getElementById("ajs-{{item.title}}")
        var element = elem[0];
        //The rest of my code...
    }
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)